# Python Pickle, avoiding module dependencies

Tags: python, ironpython, pickle

Is there a particular way to pickle objects so that pickle.load() has no dependencies on any modules? I read that while unpickling objects, Pickle tries to load the module containing the class definition of the object. Is there a way to avoid this, so that pickle.load() doesnt try to load any modules?

Answer (score 3):

May be a bit unrelated but still I would quote form the documentation:

> Warning The pickle module is not intended to be secure against erroneous or maliciously constructed data. Never unpickle data received from an untrusted or unauthenticated source.

You need to write a custom unpickler that avoids loading extra modules. A general approach will be:

- Derive your custom unpickler by subclassing `pickle.Unpickler`
- Override `find_class(..)`
- Inside `find_class(..)` Check for module and the class that needs to be loaded. Avoid loading it by raising errors.
- Use this custom class to unpickle from the string.

[Here is an excellent article](https://web.archive.org/web/20130423223601/http://nadiana.com/python-pickle-insecure) about dangers of using pickle. You would also find the code that has the above approach.

Answer (score 2):

Does not make much sense what you are asking since the serialization and deserialization of objects is the *primary* purpose of the pickle functionality. If you want something different: serialize or deserialize your objects to XML or JSON (or any other suitable format).

There is e.g. lxml.objectify or you google for "Python serialize json" or "Python serialize xml"...but you can not deserialize an object from a pickle without its class definition - at least not without further coding.

http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html

documents how to write a custom unpickler...perhaps that a good way to start - but this appears like the wrong way to do it.